# Having a bit of trouble with self-learning from Cormen et al's algo book

Tags: algorithm

I started reading Intro to Algorithms by Cormen et al like 3 weeks ago on my free time. I  finished the second chapter and have been trying out the exercises for quite a while. I find them a bit difficult.

Is this normal? Should I finish all the exercises before moving on? Or is it alright if I solve the ones I can and move on to the next chapters, possibly coming back to the exercises I can't figure out right now?

If anyone out there has had experience with this book, can you tell me how it was for you? I'm a bit discouraged on not being able to solve quite a few of the exercises here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That book was hard for me too.  We used it at the university I attended and I often had to refer to other sources to get simpler explanations when I found CLRS a little over my head.  Once I got the Wikipedia explanation straight in my head, and a code sample working (which CLRS often lacks), I found that I was able to go back to the text and make sense of it.

Don't worry about doing all of the exercises.  Even the super-elite MIT students don't have to do them all.  Do what you can do and move on.  If you need a concept in the next chapter that you had glossed over, it will still be there for you to backtrack to.

MIT OpenCourseWare has also made available the old lectures for [Introduction to Algorithms (SMA 5503)](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-046j-introduction-to-algorithms-sma-5503-fall-2005/).

Comment: I don't know if it is valid but if anyone is looking for the course above. It might be this one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-EQTVuAhSFY

Comment: @VanVO Yes, that's part of the same course. I updated the link above as well.

Comment: @BilltheLizard - The one thing wrong with all textbooks, especially CLRS is that they don't provide the solutions manuals to students. Its really bad for those who want to self study. Authors can create a separate set of problems or question banks with solutions which are shared with instructors only. This set can be used to make exams or homework. I am pretty sure that there is no dearth of problems of all levels in Algorithms. So, sharing book solutions won't make us run out of questions to ask in exams.

Comment: @VanVO - thanks for the link. Unfortunately, youtube does not allow to download videos. But, the MIT OCW link in Bill's answer allows it.

Answer (score 4):

Good for you for diving into CLRS by yourself.  You're a braver man than me.  I used the book for a grad algorithms course I took last semester, and I had a hard time just finishing the problem sets assigned for the course.  Completing all of the exercises would be a truly Herculean effort.

I'd recommend tackling the chapters that interest you most and those that you don't find to difficult.  The beginning of the book, if I remember correctly, is one of the harder parts, diving into the mathematical background of a lot of different areas of algorithms.  Chapter 5 is especially difficult unless you know a fair bit of probability theory.  Also, starred sections and problems are significantly more challenging than the surrounding material (like 21.4, which contains material our professor confessed to being unable to prove in class).  Finally at the end of the book, there is just a survey of miscellaneous topics; you can just look at those that interest you, since there are entire books written about each of those topics if you want to learn more about them.

I hope this helps, and most importantly, don't get too discouraged!  This is the seminal book on algorithms for a reason.

Comment: can you please fix the broken link to your material? @Tynan

Answer (score 3):

It's a difficult book, used by one of the pre-eminent technical universities in the world.  It's no surprise that it's challenging.  There are a LOT of exercises of varying difficulty.  It's a noble goal to attempt all of them.

Aren't the course materials on-line?  It'd be interesting to see if students taking the course for credit do all the exercises.

I wouldn't be discouraged.  Keep plugging, even if you have to pass on some of the exercises.  There's nothing saying that you have to master it in one pass, either.  Go through, take in what you can, and re-do if necessary.  You might find that the extra context helps.

The lectures are available on iTunes if you find that helps.

The important thing is to set a deadline and make steady progress.  Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

In general, it is a comprehensive and rigorous book. However, it is bad because of these:

- One-based array indexing (instead of the usual 0-based) - so everytime you translate the algorithm present in the book into code you have to either `+1` or `-1` and / or use `<` instead of `<=` or the other way around and so on.
- Bad variable naming in pseudocode - instead of `lo`, `hi` or `left`, `right` you get `p` and `q`.
- The fact that is is very rigorous may get you confused in the little details and usually you can miss the overall idea of an algorithm.

It is a famous book because many scientific papers refer to this book in their references.

Otherwise, it is ok.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with not doing all the problems is that when you are self-studying, you really don't have a good gage for how much you should be able to answer.

You can look at the [course assignments online](http://ocw.mit.edu/OcwWeb/Electrical-Engineering-and-Computer-Science/6-046JFall-2005/Assignments/index.htm), I would recommend that for figuring out problem sets to get done.

Answer (score 1):

I am learning Algorithms on my own from the CLRS book in 2020. Regardless of what people tell you about solutions manuals in general, it is advisable to get "good" solutions manuals if you are self studying with the book.

The two sets of solutions I recommend are (1) The official instructor manual and (2) solutions by Rutger's university students Michelle Bodnar and Andrew Lohr. When one of those solutions is unclear, I simply refer to the other one. If you get stuck at a problem, then give yourself a few minutes to solve it. If you don't get the answer, then use the solutions manuals. You can always test yourself on the problems from other text books or leetcode to see how much you can do on your own vs just following a solutions manual.

I won't post the solutions manuals here. I suggest that you search for them online. The Rutgers one is easily available and is legal. The official one is restricted to instructors only and is hard to get. You might be able to pay obscure online sellers/hackers to get the official one for you. Use a preloaded visa or master card gift card to make that purchase. Make sure that the card is accepted in the sellers country.

Chapter 2 was doable because I used Youtube to understand algorithms and time complexity when it was not clearly explained in the CLRS book, which is quite often. The solutions manuals also helped a little bit.

Chapter 3 is hard and I don't know if I will be able to get past this one. I might have to switch to another book, perhaps the one by Tamassia. I had studied elementary algebra, set theory, functions, probability, mathematical series and calculus a few years ago. But, I remember only a few of those things. So, it is difficult to understand Chapter 3 and move ahead.